# Accessing dynamic array elements in inline assembly

Tags: c++, inline-assembly, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to complement each letter in a dynamic array of characters and I wrote the following code 
but each time it breaks on the same line : not[esi]
I am really a novice in assembly so what should i do to fix the code?

```
void main() {
char *s1 = new char[100];
s1="Hello";
_asm {
    mov esi,s1
L1: cmp [esi],'\0'
    je done
    not [esi]
    inc esi
    jmp L1
done: 
}
for (int i = 0;i < 5;i++) {
    cout << s1[i];
}

}
```

Comment: @MichaelPetch It breaks now on the printing statement ..it tells me : error reading characters of string

Comment: I'm actually unsure how it gets that far. You first allocate space with new char[100] then you replace that pointer with  pointer to a string that is liekly read only by doing `s1 = "hello";` and then you attempt to modify a read only string with `s1[5]='\0'`

Comment: I see you modified the code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch yes.. I noticed that I copied the older version of my code then I modified it

Comment: I misread the code. `mov esi,s1` is correct . You have a problem with this `s1="Hello";` this replaces the allocated array you created on the line above with a pointer to a read only string that has Hello stored at it. You can't modify a read only string. You need to copy the string "Hello" to the s1 array.

Comment: If using C++ you should use std::string, but just as a test try replacing `s1="Hello";` with `strcpy_s(s1, 6, "hello");` . That copies the string "Hello" (including the nul terminator) to the writeable buffer you allocated for `s1`

Comment: @MichaelPetch THANK YOU SO MUCH !!! IT WORKED !!! I REALLY APPRECIATE IT ! THANK YOOOOU
I thought the error was in my assembly code